# gzipped tar archive file paths

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, gzip, tar

I am creating a `tar.gz` file containing some files and folders as follows:

```
/bin/tar cfz /usr/local/backups/mybackup-${DATENAME}.tar.gz 
                 /usr/local/backups/db-${DATENAME}.sql.gz  
                 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/myapp_folder 
                 /usr/local/tomcat/myapp.properties
```

But the paths are stored as `usr/local` that is without `/`. `tar` also gives message to remove first `/` but file is created.

Now when I transfer this file to some other system and want to uncompress it:

```
tar -zxvf mybackup-2011-APR-18.tar.gz
```

It creates `usr` directory in current directory.

How can I compress and uncompress the archive and get my files back into original folders (in `/usr` tree instead of `./usr`)?

Comment: You should consider using cpio instead.  The advantage of cpio is it takes the file list from stdin.  That way you can customize the file list when creating the archive (for example with `find`) to control the base directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
(cd / && tar -zxvf mybackup-2011-APR-18.tar.gz )
```

Alternatively you could create the archive with -P:

```
/bin/tar -P cfz /usr/local/backups/mybackup-${DATENAME}.tar.gz 
                 /usr/local/backups/db-${DATENAME}.sql.gz  
                 /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/MyApp/myapp_folder 
                 /usr/local/tomcat/myapp.properties
```

This will not remove the initial / from the filenames in the archive.

Comment: thanks I think `-P` is a better option

Comment: got this error: `/bin/tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' options`

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot - it disables absolute paths **for a reason**

Comment: tar -P -czf worked for me (note the flipped z and f).  @symcbean I totally agree, creating tar files with absolute paths is a bad idea.  But that's just my opinion.  If it were me, I'd use the first command on the untar..